# How to build WHERE IN array clause with Ecto?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

How to find posts in given List of ids?

This isn't working:

```
posts = Post |> where(id: [1, 2]) |> Repo.all
```

Example in Rails:

```
Post.where({ id: [1, 2]})
# SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id IN (1, 2)
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The following should work:

```
posts = Post |> where([p], p.id in [1, 2]) |> Repo.all
```

Comment: Returns `undefined function p/0`

Comment: @denis.peplin, you have to `import Ecto.Query`. (don't forget to algo `alias MyApp.Repo` in order to do `Repo.app`

Comment: I do have `import Ecto.query` but getting `variable "p" does not exist`

Answer (score 32):

Accepted answer gives `undefined function p/0` to me, so I came to this:

```
from(p in Post, where: p.id in [1, 2]) |> Repo.all
```

Answer (score 20):

Other posters gave both the "keywords" and "expressions" patterns needed but I wanted to comment and point out that if you are interpolating the values from a list, you need the `^` operator before the variable. You also need to be importing the module which contains the macros (special because macros have different compilation needs) before trying either of these. This is all with ecto 2.1.4, btw. So:

```
import Ecto.Query
...

id_list = [1,2,4,5,6]


# "expressions"

Post
|> where([p], p.id in ^id_list)


# "keywords"

from(p in Post, where: p.id in ^id_list)
```