# How to do 'where model.field contains array' in Ecto?

Tags: arrays, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Let's say I have a model with a field `sizes` that is an array (e.g. `sizes: ['S', 'M', 'L']`). What I want to accomplish, building an API, is for a user to be able to filter those models based on sizes. So a `GET` request to this path:

`.../products?sizes=['S','M']`

Should return all the products for which the given array is a subarray of their `sizes` field. So I don't want nor need an exact match but I want the users to be able to filter as explained above. How would I go about accomplishing this in my Phoenix API ?

I could only accomplish filtering the ones that contained a specific value (`where: this in that`), but if I pass in an array and I wanna check if that array is contained in that model field, I'm a bit lost.

Thanks in advance for any help, let me know if you need any additional information.

**EDIT**

I am trying to use `fragment("? @> ?::varchar[]", p.sizes, ^params["sizes'] )` and it works, but it fails if I add any simple filter like `[color: "red"]` on top of the existing one, this means I can't create a set of filters and then add it to the `where` clauses like `... and ^filters`

```
filters = Ecto.Changeset.cast(%Product{}, params, [], [:color])
  |> Map.fetch!(:changes)
  |> Map.to_list

# Do I need to actually do this check like this ? (It fails otherwise)
sizes = if is_nil(params["sizes"]) do [] else params["sizes"] end

products_query = from(
  p in Product,
  where: fragment("? @> ?::varchar[]", p.sizes, ^sizes) and
         ^filters
)
```

This doesn't currently work.

Comment: This answer might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36814260/how-to-build-where-in-array-clause-with-ecto

Comment: Thanks @HarrisonLucas I already saw that answer but it doesn't solve my problem as I already tried that approach.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you've figured out already, you need to use `@>` with `fragment` for the "array contains array" operation. For your second question, to chain `where` expressions with `and`, you can just add another `where`:

```
products_query = from(
  p in Product,
  where: fragment("? @> ?::varchar[]", p.sizes, ^sizes),
  where: ^filters
)
```

Comment: Of course it was that simple =/, thanks a lot for helping!